# Blazor InputFile not firing OnChange after canceling service operation

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a simple app to count the words in a file.

I chose to use Blazor to try it out, but also because a web based framework is easy to keep responsive.

I added a way to cancel the process using a `cancellationToken`. However, after I cancel the process, the `InputFile` will no longer fire it's `OnChange` event. The `InputFile` works just fine when I let the process finish and reset using the reset button. I also tried an approach with just setting `Running` to `false` but that didn't really change anything, so I don't think it's because of the tokens.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I could try to make it work properly?

Here is my Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel;
@inject FileCounterService Service

<PageTitle>File Word Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>File Word Counter</h1>

<p>Use this file upload to count the number of each unique word in your files. If multiple files are selected, the word counts are combined.</p>

@if(Service.Running)
{
    string progressString = progressPercentage + "%";

    <div id="progress" class="m-3 rounded">
        <div id="progressBar" class="rounded" style="width: @progressString">
            <p class="p-1">Loading ... @progressString</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button @onclick="@ButtonCancelClick" class="btn btn-danger mb-3">Cancel</button> 
}

@if(wordCounts == null)
{
    @if (!Service.Running)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-info mb-3">
            <i class="bi bi-info-circle m-1"></i>
            Maximum file size: 1GB. Assuming windows line endings and ANSI format.
        </div>
    }
    <InputFile OnChange="@InputFileChanged" hidden="@Service.Running" class="form-control" multiple accept=".txt" />
}
else
{
    <button @onclick="@ButtonResetClick" class="btn btn-info m-3">Reset</button>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Word</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var wordCount in wordCounts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@wordCount.Key</td>
                    <td>@wordCount.Value</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>? wordCounts = null;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private int progressPercentage;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Service.ProgressChanged += ServiceProgressChanged;
    }

    private async void InputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Service.Running)
        {
            return;
        }

        IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files = e.GetMultipleFiles();

        try
        {
            wordCounts = await Service.GetWordCounts(files, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            progressPercentage = 100;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            wordCounts = null;
            progressPercentage = 0;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void ServiceProgressChanged(object? sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        InvokeAsync(() => 
        {
            progressPercentage = args.ProgressPercentage;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    private void ButtonCancelClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    private void ButtonResetClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        wordCounts = null;
    }
}
```

FileCounterService.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWordCounter.Service
{
    public class FileCounterService
    {
        public bool Running { get; private set; }
        public event ProgressChangedEventHandler? ProgressChanged;

        private long totalBytes;
        private long progressedBytes;

        public async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>?> GetWordCounts(
            IEnumerable<IBrowserFile> files,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //initialize service
            Running = true;
            Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            //reset progress values
            totalBytes = files.Sum(x => x.Size);
            progressedBytes = 0;

            //loop each file
            foreach(IBrowserFile file in files)
            {
                //maximum file size 1 GiB should cover most of the clients files
                long maxFileSize = 1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));

                string? line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                while (line != null) 
                {
                    if (line == "")
                    {
                        line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                        continue;
                    }

                    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (wordCounts.ContainsKey(word))
                        {
                            wordCounts[word]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wordCounts.Add(word, 1);
                        }

                        //cancel execution in case cancellation was requested
                        //if (!Running) return null;
                        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Running = false;
                            throw new OperationCanceledException();
                        }
                    }

                    //since files are ANSI, we can assume 1 byte per character
                    //assuming windows line endings, so 2 additional characters per line
                    progressedBytes += line.Length + 2;

                    //multiply by 100 as float to make sure no comma values are lost
                    int progressPercentage = (int)(progressedBytes * 100f / totalBytes);
                    ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progressPercentage, null));

                    //cancel execution in case cancellation was requested
                    //if (!Running) return null;
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Running = false;
                        throw new OperationCanceledException();
                    }
                    line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                }
            }

            var returnValue = wordCounts.OrderByDescending(wordCount => wordCount.Value);

            Running = false;
            return returnValue;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not properly close the file when cancelling.

Add the `using` to this  line:

```cs
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed at least one of my issues, thanks!